# How to set selectedvalue of Dropdownlist inside a gridview with data from an SQL query using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a problem when setting the selected value of a dropdownlist inside a gridview with the data from a datatable.

I have an SQL query that selects the data that must be displayed from the dropdownlist. The dropdownlist was already populated. Therefore, the result of the query must be be displayed in the dropdownlist.

I tried below the code, but it returns the same value on each row.

This one is the code for selecting the data from database:

```
 Public Function POPULATE_DROPDOWNLIST(ByVal d_Date As Date, ByVal d_Hour As Integer)

    Using con As Odbc.OdbcConnection = New Odbc.OdbcConnection(My.Settings.DB_CONN)
        Using cmd As Odbc.OdbcCommand = _
          New Odbc.OdbcCommand( _
              "SELECT * FROM TBLDATA WHERE D_DATE='" & d_Date & _
                  "' AND DELIVERY_HOUR='" & d_Hour & "'",
              con)

            con.Open()
            Using dr As Odbc.OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Dim d_List As New List(Of String)
                While dr.Read
                    d_List.Add(dr("CRITERIA").ToString())
                End While
                con.Close()
                Return d_List
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

While this one is my code for populating gridview dropdownlist with the data returned by above function.

```
Dim dList As New List(Of String)

dList = POPULATE_DROPDOWNLIST(txtdate.Text, DropDownList1.Text)

For Each value In dList
    For i = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        Dim ddl As DropDownList = _
            DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).FindControl("dropdowncriteria"), _
                       DropDownList)
        ddl.SelectedValue = value
    Next
Next
```

Comment: hi, I wonder what do you mean by this sentence "The dropdownlist was already populated. Therefore, the result of the query must be be displayed in the dropdownlist"?

Comment: are you trying to display some data in the ddl after querying the DB, but end up all the items in ddl having the same value?

Comment: what i mean sir is the dropdownlist already have data, so the data that was returned by the query must be displayed in the dropdownlist as it's selected value..but what happens is that all dropdown rows in the grid have the same value...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Public Function POPULATE_DROPDOWNLIST(ByVal d_Date As Date, ByVal d_Hour As Integer) As DataTable
    Dim dataTable As New DataTable
    Using con As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("CS")
        Using cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "QUERY"
            con.Open()
            Dim dataAdapter As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con)
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)
            Return dataTable
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

Public Sub BIND_DDL()
    Dim previousDDLvalue As String = ddl.SelectedValue
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = POPULATE_DROPDOWNLIST(Now, 24)
    With ddl
        .Items.Clear()
        .DataSource = dt
        .DataValueField = "ID"
        .DataTextField = "DESCRIPTION"
        .DataBind()
        .SelectedValue = previousDDLvalue
    End With
End Sub
```